# How to get lines into polygons?

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-2.12

I have to create a map with the land register of a place. The data that I already have is unfortunately built out of lines and not polygons. Is there a possibility to create polygons? 
[image]

I already tried the tool “lines to polygons”, but the result is not as good as it should be (sometimes it just summarize a lot of lines to one big square). I also followed that tutorial “Lines to poly QGIS” (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsiSAK3s_jE) but I have no idea how this method should work (I tried it and the result was just one big polygon…).

Is there another good way to do so?

The aim is to get in the end one map with polygons, so that I can “click” on it and get from that polygon the information of its land register number and so on.
I use QGIS 2.12.3. -lyon

EDIT:
After using the polygonizer tool I got a good result, besides the middle part where a lot of small squares are located. The shapefile has thin lines which are connected through a circle and the polygonizer tool used those circles as polygon and not the whole square. Do I have to do something before with the lines and delete those circles?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If many of your lines generalize to one big square, this most probably means that their topology is not good (line are not exactly touching, therefore the polygon cannot be delineated).

You could use the GRASS GIS [v.clean](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass71/manuals/v.clean.html) command in order to snap the lines that are nearly touching. Make sure that you work on a copy because this modify the whole dataset. There is a [GRASS plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/grass_integration/grass_integration.html) to use GRASS from QGIS.

Comment: when I search for GRASS, I just get a tool called "generalizer". Is it this? And if, which algorithm I should use?

Answer (score 1):

Try the polygonize tool vector instead, it can give good results where the lines to polygons tool fails. You can find it by searching the processing toolbox.

[image]

Comment: where exactly can I find that tool? If I go to Processing Toolbox I can choose between geoalgorithms, model and script... is that right so far?

Comment: You can either search in the search bar at the top of the window (where I wrote 'Polygonize' in the screenshot above), or go to QGIS geoalgorithms > Vector geometry tools > Polygonize.

Comment: I am sorry, but when I write this, there is no result at all... Do I have to install it first or use a different programm but QGIS? I also can't find it as a plugin.. can that be?

Comment: @user69896 - Check in the bottom of the _Processing Toolbox_ that is says **"Advanced interface"** and **not "Simplified interface"**.

Comment: ahh great, now I found it! Thanks a lot! It's processing right now, I will let you know about the result :)

Comment: The tool worked great at most parts. But as I edited my question now, it used the little circles in between as a polygon and not the square arround it. Do I have to do something before with those cirles?

Comment: Yes, you may have to do some cleaning up either before or after running the tool.